# common objects in two given objetcs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a java script code in which i have to change the style of common object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var obj1=$("p:contains('Z')");  //output p:3
var obj2=$("p:contains('C')");  //output p:1 and p:3
 printCommon(obj1,obj2).css("color","red");   //it should change p3 color to red 

});
```

what will be the best approach to do this. What am I supposed to write inside printCommon function

My HTML is as follow.

```
 <p>A-B-C</p>
 <p>D-B-T</p>
 <p>I-Z-C</p>
```

Comment: It's not clear what's your question.

Comment: Have you tried to crate your own implementation of`printCommon` and run into specific issues? if so you should put what issues you have. If you have not, give it a try and then ask questions if you run into trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter each item in one collection to see if the other collection contains it.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/1bv963pk/1/

```
function printCommon($ob1, $ob2) {
    return $ob1.filter(function () {
        return $ob2.is(this);
    });
}
```

This works because `is` will return true if the item matches *any* element in its collection.

This can be reduced to a filter of one list by the other:

**JSFIddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/1bv963pk/2/

```
function printCommon($ob1, $ob2) {
    return $ob1.filter($ob2);
}
```

Comment: @Vishal Srivastava: Please check my updated fiddle (with extra elements to show it will match any with elements in common).

Comment: what if i need to merge these two object.

Comment: filter will not give correct output if $obj1 < $obj2

Comment: @Vishal Srivastava: Please explain what you mean? Are these different questions? If you have specific examples, update my JSFiddle.

Comment: yes..like merge(obj1,obj2) should give p1 and p3 object

Comment: @ Vishal Srivastava: For a merge just use `add` e.g. `var merged = obj1.add(obj2)`. That does not include elements more than once in the new collection. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/1bv963pk/3/